# multiprocessing with textacy or spacy

Tags: python, multiprocessing, spacy, pool, textacy

I am trying to speed up processing of large lists of texts via parallelisation of textacy. When I use Pool from multiprocessing the resulting textacy corpus comes out empty. I am not sure if the problem is in the way I use textacy or multiprocessing paradigm?
Here is the example that illustrates my issue:

```
import spacy
import textacy
from multiprocessing import Pool

texts_dict={
"key1":"First text 1."
,"key2":"Second text 2."
,"key3":"Third text 3."
,"key4":"Fourth text 4."
}

model=spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

# this works

corpus = textacy.corpus.Corpus(lang=model)

corpus.add(tuple([value, {'key':key}],) for key,value in texts_dict.items())

print(corpus) # prints Corpus(4 docs, 8 tokens)
print([doc for doc in corpus])

# now the same thing with a worker pool returns empty corpus

corpus2 = textacy.corpus.Corpus(lang=model)

pool = Pool(processes=2) 
pool.map( corpus2.add, (tuple([value, {'key':key}],) for key,value in texts_dict.items()) )

print(corpus2) # prints Corpus(0 docs, 0 tokens)
print([doc for doc in corpus2])

# to make sure we get the right data into corpus.add
pool.map( print, (tuple([value, {'key':key}],) for key,value in texts_dict.items()) )
```

Textacy is based on spacy. Spacy doesn't support multithreading but supposedly should be OK to run in multiple processes. https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2075

As per great suggeston of @constt https://stackoverflow.com/a/58317741/4634344 the collecting of the results into the corpus works for a datasets as large as n_docs= 10273 n_sentences= 302510 n_tokens= 2053129.

For a larger dataset (16000 docs 3MM tokens) I get a following error:

```
result_corpus=corpus.get() 
  File "<string>", line 2, in get
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 772, in _callmethod
    raise convert_to_error(kind, result)
multiprocessing.managers.RemoteError: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unserializable message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 283, in serve_client
    send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 393, in _send_bytes
    header = struct.pack("!i", n)
struct.error: 'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647
```

´
I will investigate but if you have a direct solution - much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the fact that python processes run in separate memory spaces, you have to share your `corpus` object between processes in the pool. To do this, you have to wrap the `corpus` object into a sharable class which you'll register with a [BaseManager](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-managers) class. Here is how you can refactor your code to make it work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

import spacy
import textacy


texts = {
    'key1': 'First text 1.',
    'key2': 'Second text 2.',
    'key3': 'Third text 3.',
    'key4': 'Fourth text 4.',
}


class PoolCorpus(object):

    def __init__(self):
        model = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
        self.corpus = textacy.corpus.Corpus(lang=model)

    def add(self, data):
        self.corpus.add(data)

    def get(self):
        return self.corpus


BaseManager.register('PoolCorpus', PoolCorpus)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    with BaseManager() as manager:
        corpus = manager.PoolCorpus()

        with Pool(processes=2) as pool:
            pool.map(corpus.add, ((v, {'key': k}) for k, v in texts.items()))

        print(corpus.get())
```

Output:

```
Corpus(4 docs, 16 tokens)
```

Comment: Thanks for a very clear suggestion! I have run it on the example and a smaller real dataset (n_docs= 153 n_sentences= 953 n_tokens= 7600) with no issues. However for a dataset with 16000 docs and ca. 3MM tokens an error arise. 
I will add the error message to the question.

Comment: n_docs= 10273 n_sentences= 302510 n_tokens= 2053129 went through as well

Comment: @Diego have you tried to split documents into chunks of length, say 10000, and process them sequentially in a pool using the same shared corpus?

Comment: Yes I have just did that and it works fine up to same limit. 
The number 2,147,483,647 (or hexadecimal 7FFF,FFFF16) is the maximum positive value for a 32-bit signed binary integer in computing. I run 64-bit python. It seems this is the issue that affects me https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/731#issuecomment-409893849 But it has to be fixed already (but in Python  3.8?) Stage:  resolved
Components:   Versions:  Python 3.8

Comment: I tried to install python 3.8 but there is no wheel for scipy (openblas,lapack) so I abandoned this avenue for now. Anyway, unfortunately the parallel execution as above doesn't bring any speed-up compared to a single process. I wonder if I should post my findings here or accept your answer and start another question?